# Updating Slicer with VBA (OLAP Data Feed)

Tags: excel, vba

I want to update a Slicer connected to an OLAP data feed with VBA but I am running into an error that I can't figure out.

```
Sub update_slicer()

    Dim sc As SlicerCache
    Dim sL As SlicerCacheLevel
    Dim sI As SlicerItem
    Dim slicerItems_array

    Set sc = ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Sales_Month_Full_Name")
    Set sL = sc.SlicerCacheLevels(1)

    slicerItems_array = Array("Jun-19", "Jul-19")
    sc.VisibleSlicerItemsList = slicerItems_array
End Sub
```

Error Message:

> Run-time error '1004': 
>   XML for Analysis parser: The restriction value provided by the consumer either does not match other restrictions or refers to an unknown object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this helps someone. The slicerItem was actually "[TIME].Sales Month Full Name.Jun-19". I ran a quick loop on the SlicerCacheLevel to figure that one out.